# problems in importing theano

Tags: python, theano

I am running python on windows but when I import theano, I come across this problem:

```
import theano
```

> WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be
>   unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU)
>   and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be
>   severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an
>   empty string.

Comment: So, what do you need help with?

Comment: Hi @imsaurav-karna, have you installed g++?

Comment: I installed g++ from mingw.org. Now what I am getting is AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof' while importing theano

Comment: Please look to my answer for complete giude: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41401271/7349628

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a **problem**, it's a **WARNING** as it very clearly says. It just means that you don't have g++ installed on your system and `theano` won't be able to apply optimizations.

To remove this, just install `g++` or do as it very clearly says:

> **To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.**

Comment: I tried installing g++ but could not succeed. Could you please share some better ways to install g++ without any hiccups?

Comment: Have you got Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes Visual studio 2012 redistributables version 14.0.0.1

Comment: I am getting this AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof'