# Python, keras new installation

Tags: python, keras

I just installed keras 1.1.2, using Windows 64-bit and Python 2.7.

The code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(25, input_dim=50, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
```

returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Loopy\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-3-850dd91f408b>", line 30, in <module>
    model.add(Dense(25, input_dim=50, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'input_dim'
```

the code

```
model.add(Dense(15, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Loopy\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-4-85741da8f45c>", line 1, in <module>
    model.add(Dense(15, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: You didn't mention anything about how you installed python/keras, and that information is very relevant here.

Comment: I installed it using pip command.

Comment: I also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097988/how-do-i-install-keras-and-theano-in-anaconda-python-2-7-on-windows - it didn't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Keras and Theano in Anaconda Python 2.7 on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097988/how-do-i-install-keras-and-theano-in-anaconda-python-2-7-on-windows)

Comment: What is the context of your code?

Comment: Just a neural network for classification problem.

Comment: `model.add(Dense(25,input_shape=(50,),activation='relu'))` try this line. The problem is you have updated keras library but using old api code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade your keras to latest 1.1.2 by using the following command:

```
pip install keras --upgrade
```

For a specific user: `pip install --user keras --upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help - I already tried to uninstall it, and upgrade... Probably the issue is with Anaconda - the upgrade doesn't work on scipy upgrade: Failed to build scipy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the layers separately ? Input then Dense then Initializers and then Activation. 
Other than that, try to use `kernel_initializer='random_uniform'`rather than `init='uniform'`.