# Fatal error while installing keras

Tags: python, git, anaconda, keras, lstm

I was trying to install keras (for using LSTM) on my Windows 10 system in Anaconda using the [method provided by Yelaman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975902/4169943). But after running the command `pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git`, I received the following fatal error -

> C:\Anaconda>pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
>
> Collecting git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
>
> Cloning  git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git to
>   c:\users\krishna\appdata\local\temp\pip-reettr-build fatal: protocol
>   error: bad line length character:
>
> Er
>
> Command "git clone -q git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
>   c:\users\krishna\appdata\local\temp\pip-reettr-build" failed with
>   error code 128 in None

I don't have a github account but i use `git` using bitbucket (if that matters).

Could anyone explain to me what error I am committing and if there is a way out? My main goal is to use keras in Anaconda in Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using a unix system for Theano, as I have not succeeded installing it on my Windows due to compiler errors. On unix on the other hand it is very simple to install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error may be because we have a git repository listed as a dependency. Not still fully sure, though. ([Source](https://circleci.com/docs/git-pip-install/))

The solution is to replace `pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git` with `pip install git+http://github.com/Theano/Theano.git` i.e. replacing the second `git` with `http` (this works since the repository is public)