# Using multiple gpus on windows using theano,keras

Tags: gpu, theano, keras, theano-cuda

I am a beginner in deep learning/theano/keras.I'm trying to figure out how to  use multiple gpus on windows 7. I've had success installing Theano,keras(as described in this post [How do I install Keras and Theano in Anaconda Python on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097988/how-do-i-install-keras-and-theano-in-anaconda-python-on-windows)) and using one gpu. I want to use both my gpus

Following are the details of configs and versions

Python - 2.7(Anaconda-4.3.14,Windows-64bit)
,CUDA - 7.5.17
,Theano - 0.9.0rc3
,keras - 1.2.2
,pycuda - 2016.1.2+cuda7518
,gpu - Geforce GTX 480(2 of them)

Theano configuration is as below
.theanorc.txt

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu

[nvcc]
flags=-LC:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\libs
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin

[lib]
cnmem=0.8
```

Currently I'm able to use only one GPU and I am getting memory error as below when I try to fit the model

MemoryError: ('Error allocating 411041792 bytes of device memory (CNMEM_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY).', "you might consider using 'theano.shared(..., borrow=True)'")

Does using 2 gpus solve the problem(if yes, how do I enable the second one?)
or is my model too big ?

Thank You

Comment: Reduce `cnmem` value to 0.5 or even to zero first and check if the `CNMEM_STATUS` error goes away. You can do multi-gpu training with Keras+Tensorflow. See [here](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) and [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2436).

Comment: Hi @ParagS.Chandakkar, I tried cnmem to zero, and I got this error.MemoryError: ('Error allocating 67108864 bytes of device memory (out of memory).', "you might consider using 'theano.shared(..., borrow=True)'")

Comment: Hi @ParagS.Chandakkar, I can't install tensorflow on Windows as my GPU's Compute Capability is < 3.0

Comment: If you have complex model try to lower down the batchsize it might help with the memory issue

Comment: Hi @oak, My batch size is 5.Should I lower it even further ? any other ideas ?

Comment: @RaviTeja using `keras` and `batchsize`. `Keras` engine tries to load all the batch size in once. This may cause memory issue. But 5 is not a big batch. How big is your network?

Comment: I actually precomputed the convolution layers.I simply loaded these precomputed  conv_layer outputs and used them as input for fully connected layers.The input to the network is 512x14x14 .The network is Maxpool-Flatten-(Dense(4096)-Dropout(0.5)-Batchnorm-)x2 - Softmax(5 units). The stride in maxpool is 2