# starting jupyter notebook from ubuntu's bash installed on windows 10

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-10, jupyter-notebook

When I type `jupyter notebook` in the ubuntu bash installed on windows 10, a file is opened inside the shell which looks like this

```
Jupyter1NotebookNrequirespJavaScript.g one-time-token-authenticated connection from 127.0.0.1
Please enable it to proceed.
Jupyter Notebook
Logout

  • Files
  • Running
  • Clusters

Select items to perform actions on them.
Duplicate Rename Move Download Shutdown View Edit
[                    ] Upload
New

  • Notebook:
  •
  • Other:
  • Text File
  • Folder
  • Terminal

[ ]  Toggle Dropdown

  • Folders
  • All Notebooks
  • Running
  • Files

  •

Last Modified
Name
Currently running Jupyter processes
Terminals
There are no terminals running.
Notebooks
There are no notebooks running.
Clusters tab is now provided by IPython parallel. See IPython parallel for installation details.
```

I tried to type `jupyter notebook --no_browser` the notebook starts but it keeps stopping reconnecting all the time. Also the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975902/3551661) didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that Ubuntu on Windows, just as a normal Ubuntu installation of jupyter would, tries to open the default browser, only that in "Ubuntu on Windows"'s case, it can't open the actual default browser of your Windows system and instead opens "w3m". Therefore, you need to quit "w3m" by hitting Q -> y. Then, you should see the output that you would expect when starting "jupyter notebook":

```
[C 12:30:49.819 NotebookApp]

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=846b1a3b51e3c3adb2cb756a887f178975de1e11c90ada10
```

From there on out, the procedure is exactly the same as normally. Copy the provided URL with token into your actual Windows browser, and code along.