# dimshuffle.c missing in theano directory (for keras)

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, keras, theano

I just started working with keras which I've installed from the top comment from here:
 [How do I install Keras and Theano in Anaconda Python on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097988/how-do-i-install-keras-and-theano-in-anaconda-python-on-windows)

I can import theano and keras in the python command line, but when I try running [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py) code, I keep getting an error in line 44 saying:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\c_code\dimshuffle.c'

I checked in the directory and the said file is missing, but I can't seem to find any documentation about it. 
Did anyone else encounter this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem with Theano 0.10.0.dev1. After downgrading 0.9.0 it worked. I am using pip, not conda. However there could be another problem due to depreciation of cuda. I am getting this warning message for example:

> WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): The cuda backend is deprecated and will be removed in the next release (v0.10).  Please switch to the gpuarray backend. You can get more information about how to switch at this URL:
>    https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29

Therefore you may need to reconfigure your `.theanorc`. Here is mine:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu

[cuda]
root =/usr/local/cuda-6.0/cuda

[nvcc]
fastmath = True
flags=-I/usr/local/cuda-6.0/include

[blas]
ldflags = -lopenblas

[lib]
cnmem = 0.9
```