# Error when installing keras using theano backend on Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, keras, theano, keras-layer

I am trying to install keras with theano backend on anaconda on windows,

I followed the steps in the link:

[How do I install Keras and Theano in Anaconda Python on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097988/how-do-i-install-keras-and-theano-in-anaconda-python-on-windows)

The installation did not give an error, but when I run a simple code like:

```
    from keras.models import Sequential
    print('rrrrrrrrrrrrrr')
```

I get the following error:

```
        File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
from keras.models import Sequential
 File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import utils
 File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import conv_utils
 File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
from .. import backend as K
 File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
from .theano_backend import *
 File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 3, in <module>
import theano
File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
from theano.compile import (
File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from theano.compile.mode import *
File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in <module>
import theano.gof.vm
File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 673, in <module>
from . import lazylinker_c
File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
preargs=args)
 File "C:\Users\alihd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2353, in compile_str
(status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
  Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): 
  C:\Users\alihd\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.15063-
 AMD64_Family_21_Model_112_Stepping_0_AuthenticAMD-2.7.13-
 64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mo.  ^include 
  <Python.h>
```

In order to run the code, I set backend to theano using:

```
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
 python test.py  #includes the python code
```

I am using Python 2.7.13