# Python 2.7 compilation failure (theano), windows 10

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, theano, lasagne

I tried looking at what others have done with problem similar to mine, but I still get the same error. I have no idea what's causing it. I've tried following: 
[How to install Theano on Anaconda Python 2.7 x64 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687103/how-to-install-theano-on-anaconda-python-2-7-x64-on-windows)

but that didn't help.

I'm trying to run this example, but with my own dataset: https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/examples/mnist.py

Error message is as follows, I didn't include the 787 other lines inbetween:

```
C:\Anaconda2\python.exe "C:/Users/mikrolab/Dropbox/Skole UiS/4. semester/Master/Master/hoved/ansiktsgjenkjenning/sklearntest.py" mlp 400

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\tensor\signal\downsample.py:6: UserWarning: downsample module has been moved to the theano.tensor.signal.pool module.
  "downsample module has been moved to the theano.tensor.signal.pool module.")

Loading data...
Building model and compiling functions...
WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock): Overriding existing lock by dead process '10436' (I am process '16120')


Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\g++.bat -shared -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -march=core2 -mcx16 -msahf -mno-movbe -mno-aes -mno-pclmul -mno-popcnt -mno-abm -mno-lwp -mno-fma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mno-bmi -mno-bmi2 -mno-tbm -mno-avx -mno-avx2 -mno-sse4.2 -msse4.1 -mno-lzcnt --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=6144 -mtune=core2 -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m32 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof -o C:\Users\mikrolab\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.10586-Intel64_Family_6_Model_23_Stepping_10_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-32\tmpahcj6d\df1196e30ea06df2bcfcd011958dc6f5.pyd C:\Users\mikrolab\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.10586-Intel64_Family_6_Model_23_Stepping_10_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-32\tmpahcj6d\mod.cpp -LC:\Anaconda2\libs -LC:\Anaconda2 -lpython27

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/mikrolab/Dropbox/Skole UiS/4. semester/Master/Master/hoved/ansiktsgjenkjenning/sklearntest.py", line 312, in <module>

C:\Users\mikrolab\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.10586-Intel64_Family_6_Model_23_Stepping_10_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-32\tmpahcj6d\mod.cpp: In member function 'int {anonymous}::__struct_compiled_op_df1196e30ea06df2bcfcd011958dc6f5::run()':

C:\Users\mikrolab\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.10586-Intel64_Family_6_Model_23_Stepping_10_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-32\tmpahcj6d\mod.cpp:457:34: error: cannot convert 'npy_int64* {aka long long int*}' to 'npy_intp* {aka int*}' in argument passing

main(**kwargs)

File "C:/Users/mikrolab/Dropbox/Skole UiS/4.semester/Master/Master/hoved/ansiktsgjenkjenning/sklearntest.py", line 245, in main
    updates = updates)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\function.py", line 322, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 480, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1779, in orig_function
    defaults)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1643, in create
    input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\link.py", line 690, in make_thunk
    storage_map=storage_map)[:3]

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\vm.py", line 1005, in make_all
    no_recycling))

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\op.py", line 978, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\op.py", line 881, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1200, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1143, in compile
    keep_lock=keep_lock)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1595, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1142, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1506, in compile_cmodule
    preargs=preargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2204, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', mrg_uniform{TensorType(float32, 4D),inplace}(<TensorType(int32, matrix)>, MakeVector{dtype='int64'}.0), '\n', "Compilation failed (return status=1): 

C:\\Users\\mikrolab\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.10586-Intel64_Family_6_Model_23_Stepping_10_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-32\\tmpahcj6d\\mod.cpp: In member function 'int {anonymous}::__struct_compiled_op_df1196e30ea06df2bcfcd011958dc6f5::run()':\r. 

C:\\Users\\mikrolab\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.10586-Intel64_Family_6_Model_23_Stepping_10_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-32\\tmpahcj6d\\mod.cpp:457:34: error: cannot convert 'npy_int64* {aka long long int*}' to 'npy_intp* {aka int*}' in argument passing\r. ", '[*1 -> mrg_uniform{TensorType(float32, 4D),inplace}(<TensorType(int32, matrix)>, <TensorType(int64, vector)>), *1::1]')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Solved**: Followed every part of the following instructions: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows

did this as well: Why can't nvcc find my Visual C++ installation?

Theano is working now and is using my GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 with Anaconda as you have to use the same compiler they used for packages you compile to be compatible.  They do have mingw bindings but I'm not sure how compatible they are.

Comment: Meaning I should install Visual Studio first, then Anaconda followed up with Theano?

Comment: No just compile Theano with Visual Studio 2010 since you're using Anaconda 2.7.  May I ask why you don't just open a command prompt window and type > `conda install theano`

Comment: Reinstalling and updating Anaconda now. Will try that as well.

Comment: But I will not get the "Bleeding edge" version of Theona then?

Comment: You won't get the development version so then I see why you want to compile it.

Comment: > conda install theano did not work btw. Theona itself isn't the issue I think, its the compiler..

Comment: Uninstalled MinGW and got the script working now. but its painfully slow. It's supposed to iterate through a batchsize of 500 and it takes about 1 minute for each batch...

Comment: Odd the conda didn't work, maybe you're behind a firewall... Does pip work?

Comment: yes, but I have theano installed, thats not the issue. The issue is the compiler.