# How to install Theano for Python 3.5 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, theano

I can't find how one is supposed to install Theano for Python 3.5 (Windows 10) only for Python 2.7.

I don't want to have to downgrade to 2.7 so does anyone know how to install Theano for Python 3.5 (on Windows 10)?

A clear set of step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated, as well as other things I need and how to install them.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687103/how-to-install-theano-on-anaconda-python-2-7-x64-on-Windows) is on how to install it with Python 2.7. If you install Anaconda for Python 3.5 instead of 2.7, then I guess it will work without many differences.

Answer (score 1):

To make this question more self contained I find it worth to add this answer:

[Winpython](https://winpython.github.io/) is the best!!, actually it is the recommended installation over windows, [read here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#scientific-python-distribution). It comes with python 3.5 fully loaded with all the dependencies including numpy, scipy, scikit, theano, keras, ipython, jupyter and more, actually you don't need to do anything or to change any configurations, all you need to do (if you want to enable GPU) is to download [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) (and of course you should have visual C++) and finally add this variable to your environment variables:

Variable name: THEANO_FLAGS

Variable value: floatX=float32,device=gpu,nvcc.fastmath=True,lib.cnmem=0.8

(lib.cnmem=0.8) can be equal to any value, this means that cuda will use 80% of your GPU memory

If you need any other clarification let me know in the comments